# Woocommerce hide the price for specific products

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

In my woocommerce store I have multiple products. Some products have prices but some products are just offers. The offers shouldnt have a price. I tried leaving the price field open. That doesnt work. And putting it on 0 is just ugly. I would like for some products to be displayed without a price. Is there a possible way to do this?

I'd like to hear it,

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So , can users add them to cart as free stuff ???

Comment: @Alice Yes, those are free services that we offer. Users can request them? ls that so weird xd ?

Comment: No, not weird... that is easy... and u already got the ans....good luck

Comment: but try the code and see whether you can proceed checkout without price....If not i will pitch in ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible but you need some custom code added to your functions.php file.

Here is a very good tutorials explaining how to achieve that: https://jeroensormani.com/hiding-product-prices-woocommerce/

The last part is about hiding for specific products by id.

Comment: Thanks, exactly what i need.